# Is this the correct contrapositive of the given statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Given some sequence $f_n$ and a function $f$, I want to prove the following statement:

If $\forall$ subsequences $\{f_{n_k}\}$ $\exists$ a further subsequence $\{f_{n_{k_j}}\}$ s.t. $\{f_{n_{k_j}}\} \to f $, then $\{f_n\} \to f$.

It's been a while since I've used contrapositive in a proof, so I was hoping to get confirmation that this is the correct contrapositive:

If $\{f_n \}$ does not converge to $f$, then $\exists$ a subsequence $\{ f_{n_k}  \}$ s.t. $\forall$ further subsequences $\{ f_{n_{k_j}} \}$, those subsequences won't converge to $f$.

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Hurray.  You did it.

Comment: Great job, mate!